# Post array from form using xmlhttprequest

Tags: php, forms, xmlhttprequest

I have an php generated table/form with checkboxes like this:

```
    if ($query) {
if (!mysqli_num_rows($query)) {
    //Empty storage
    echo "There are no items in '$storage'.";
    exit();
} else {
    //form
    echo "<form name='send_parts_form' action='../includes/generatetab.php' method='post'>";
    //Table header
    echo "
        <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Part</th>
            <th>PN</th>
            <th>Manufactured</th>
            <th>Serial</th>
            <th>Site</th>
            <th>Date replaced</th>
            <th>By user</th>
            <th>Faulty</th>
            <th>Send</th>
            <th>Select</th>
        </tr>";
    //Retrieved data
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['part_type'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['pn'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['manufactured'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['serial'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['site_id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['user'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['faulty'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='send_parts[]' class='checkclass' value=" . $row['id'] . "></td>";
        echo "</tr>";};
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</br>";
    echo "</br>";
    echo "<input type='button' onclick='sendToZG()' value='Send'/>";
    echo "</br>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Generate tab' />";
    echo "</form>";
    exit();
}
    } else {
    die("Query failed");
   }
```

User then checks option they want and upon submiting (Generate tab) they get tab delimited text with values they selected.
I now want when they click "Send" to have values posted to another php page and results returned on the same page (under SentList div). I have js like this:

```
    //Browser Support Code
    function sendToZG(){
var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }catch (e) {
    try{
     ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }catch (e){
     // Something went wrong
     alert("Your browser broke!");
     return false;
    }
    }
    }

    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200){
    var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('SentList');
    ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
    }

    // Now get the value from page and pass it to server script.
    var formData = new FormData( document.getElementsByName("send_parts")[0] );
    ajaxRequest.open('POST', "../includes/sendtozg.php", true);
    ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajaxRequest.send("send_parts=" + formData);
    }
```

Edited: ajaxRequest.send("send_part=" + formData); to ajaxRequest.send("send_parts=" + formData);
Now it returns:

Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 53 (That is where I fetch my data in sendtozg.php).

I'll add sendtozg.php at the end of the post.

If instead of:

```
    <form name='send_parts_form' action='../includes/generatetab.php' method='post'>
```

I echo:

```
    <form name='send_parts_form' action='../includes/sendtozg.php' method='post'>
```

Upon submit, script sendtozg.php gets executed fine but on a different page.

So basically what I'm trying to do is to have 2 options for the php generated form:

> 1. Generate tab delimited txt file
> 2. Execute sendtozg.php and return results on same page

I already have both scripts (generatetab.php and sendtozg.php) and they work fine.

sendtozg.php:

```
    if (!empty($_POST['send_parts'])){
foreach ($_POST['send_parts'] as $send_parts){
$getchecked = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM $storage WHERE id=$send_parts");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getchecked)) {
    $copypart = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO sent_parts (part_type, pn, manufactured, serial, site_id, date, user, faulty, log)
                                    SELECT part_type, pn, manufactured, serial, site_id, date, user, faulty, log 
                                    FROM $storage WHERE id=$send_parts");                                       

    // check to see if it copied
    $getserial = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT serial FROM $storage WHERE id=$send_parts");
    $getserial_row = mysqli_fetch_array($getserial, MYSQLI_NUM);
    $foundserial = $getserial_row[0];
    $checkcopy = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM sent_parts WHERE serial = '$foundserial'");

    // add user info and date
    $addinfo = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE sent_parts SET sent2zg='$user', date2zg='$strdate' WHERE serial = '$foundserial'");

    if (!$check1_res) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();
    };

    //delete from storage
    if($checkcopy > 0) {
        $getpart = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT part_type FROM sent_parts WHERE serial='$foundserial'");
        $getpart_row = mysqli_fetch_array($getpart, MYSQLI_NUM);
        $deletedpart = $getpart_row[0];
        $removepart = mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM $storage WHERE id = '$send_parts'");
        echo "Part " . $deletedpart . " has been transfered";
    } else {
        echo "Part " . $row['part_type'] . "was NOT transfered";
    };      
};
    } exit ();
    } else {
echo "Nothing was selected, please try again!";
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried making a third PHP file and merely `include '../includes/generatetab.php';` and `include '../includes/sendtozg.php';`, then send the form to that file?

Comment: Wouldn't that execute both scripts? I would like to keep them separate, so either could be executed separately.

Comment: Ah, I see, execute `generatetab.php` OR `sendtozg.php` depending on user action. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right! They can both be executed by xmlhttprequest or in some other way. Important is that the result is returned on the same page for sendtozg.php, the generatetab.php downloads txt file anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<form>` doesn't have an `id` attribute on it so you'll either need to add `id="send_parts"` to the `<form>` or you'll need to change your code from `getElementById` to `getElementsByName` like this:

```
// Now get the value from page and pass it to server script.
// Serialize the data
var formData = new FormData( document.getElementsByName("send_parts")[0] );
ajaxRequest.open('POST', "../includes/sendtozg.php", true);
ajaxRequest.send(formData);
```

Then inside sendtozg.php you'll need to change the first two lines to:

```
if (!empty($_POST)){
  foreach ($_POST as $send_parts){
```

Comment: Tried it, but it prints now: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 53 (That is where I fetch my data in sendtozg.php). You can look at my edited post. I included sendtozg.php

Comment: @spiro2903 See my edit which explains how to change sendtozg.php.

Comment: Did all You wrote, then i got "WebKitFormBoundary" so I deleted "ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader" in sendtozg.js, then I got error at line "$getchecked=..." in sendtozg.php so i changed id=$send_parts to id='$send_parts'. Now I get no results or printouts.

Comment: If I add: print_r ($send_parts); after foreach and before $getchecked, with one item selected I get: Array ( [0] => 10 ). I also added: ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"); to sendtozg.js

Comment: Solved it, sendtozg.php should be: if (!empty($_POST)){
   foreach ($_POST['send_parts'] as $send_parts){ Thanks for the help. I'll give You the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code for the sendtozg.js:

```
// Get get the value from page and pass it to server script.
var formData = new FormData( document.getElementsByName("send_parts")[0] );

ajaxRequest.open('POST', "../includes/sendtozg.php", true);
ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
ajaxRequest.send(formData);
}
```

and sendtozg.php should be:

```
    if (!empty($_POST)){
    foreach ($_POST['send_parts'] as $send_parts){
    $getchecked = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM $storage WHERE id=$send_parts");
```

By the way:

```
    print_r ($some_array)
```

and

```
    if (!$check1_res) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();
    };
```

Are great tools for troubleshooting.